# Connecting AWS API Gateway to internet facing https ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-elb

Here is the use case - we have a public facing https ALB with a custom domain certificate.  The domain name resolves to cloud front currently, but of course I can override that in my /etc/hosts

This flow works CloudFront -> internet facing https ALB.

I can't get this flow to work and can't find any docs saying it's possible

AWS API Gateway -> internet facing https ALB

I appreciate the use case probably seems a bit odd (why not use internal ALB, right?), but as far as I can tell this isn't possible.  The custom domain on the public facing https ALB doesn't appear to compatible with API Gateway. ie: Gateway fails to negotiation cert / tls with ALB.

If anyone knows different and how to make this work (maybe I'm missing an option?) please let me know.

Curiously, this seems to imply it works:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-application-load-balancers/

"5.    In the Endpoint URL field, enter either the Application Load Balancer's default DNS name or custom DNS name. If you use the default DNS name, enter http:// as the URL scheme. If you use a custom DNS name, enter https:// as the URL scheme."

Perhaps it's trying to say that it only works if DNS resolves to that LB for that custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I can tell this isn't possible

It is possible. This is exactly why [HTTP integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html) are used for.

EDIT:

You must have **your own domain** with your own valid public **SSL certificate** from AWS ACM. You can't use any SSL certificate for a default domain of LB as this domain does not belong to you. It belongs to AWS.

Comment: I don't believe it is and there is no documentation which explicitly says it's possible.

Think about how cert negotiation works, you need to make a proper TLS request with the correct host name.   You can't just go curl -H "Host: customdomain.com" https:loadbalancer_dns_name

Cloudfront -> ELB is doing something weird, I suspect.

Comment: @Blaze It works, because I was doing that. Off course you need proper ssl certificate and your own domain.

Comment: @Blaze Even the link you posted in your question to AWS docs explains that it works and you need https listener.

Comment: I suspect you probably have a domain name resolving to a public facing LB.  The documentation I linked to is likely saying that.

Comment: @Blaze You must have your own domain. You can't use any SSL certificate for a default domain of LB as this domain does not belong to you. It belongs to AWS. I added that info to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what "have your own domain" means.  Do you mean to say it must resolve in DNS to the public LB?  Yes, that's true.  But having a proper ACM SSL certificate with the domain is not sufficient.

Comment: @Blaze You have to have domain with you own or at least control, e.g. `myapplication.org` which will point to a default domain of your LB. Once you have your own domain, it you can obtain a free SSL certificate for it using AWS ACM. Then have the certificate you associate it with your https listener.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think. you actually read the original post even once.   The point is there is no DNS pointing at the LB, but rather Cloudfront.  I stated that very clearly in the OP